# How to find elements which is exists in multiple array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have to find the elements which exist in multiple arrays,

For example, I have 4 arrays

```
Array1 = {P1,P2,P3,P4}
Array2 = {P1,P2,P3}
Array3 = {P1}
Array4 = {P2,P3}
```

I have to find elements which exist in all the arrays i.e for the above example the elements im expecting is {P1,P2} or {P1,P3}

How can i do this using PHP array functions?

Please help.

Comment: This seems to be what you're looking for: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: Dup of [Find common values in multiple arrays with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299608/find-common-values-in-multiple-arrays-with-php)

Comment: I thought array_intersect will give only element(s) which are present in all the arrays! Isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

use the [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) function of php

Comment: I thought array_intersect will give only element(s) which are present in all the arrays! Isn't it?

Comment: @srinath: _I have to find the common elements in multiple arrays. I have to find elements which exist in all the arrays_. So what do you really wants? If this is not your question then what is your question?

Comment: Edited my question, "I have to find elements which exist in all the arrays" is THE question. I think the example should make it clear..

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in PHP function that will do what you're asking for called array_intersect

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: I thought array_intersect will give only element(s) which are present in all the arrays! Isn't it?