# Check arrays to find common data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find common values in multiple arrays with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299608/find-common-values-in-multiple-arrays-with-php)

I'm trying to find the number of friends two users have in common. Each users friends user id's are stored in  the data base like this: 12, 13, 14. This is my code.

```
$my_friends = explode(',', $my_friends);
print_r($my_friends);
```

This outputs: `Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => 13 [2] => 14 )`

These are my friends user id's. Now for the next user:

```
$users_friends = explode(',', $users_friends);
print_r($users_friends);
```

This outputs: `Array ( [0] => 12 )`

How do I show that user 1 and user 2 have id 12 in common ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299608/find-common-values-in-multiple-arrays-with-php

Comment: Why not do this in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).

```
print_r(array_intersect($my_friends, $users_friends));
```

will output `Array ( [0] => 12 )`

Answer (score 4):

Besides suggesting that you should normalise your database, which would make this easy to do with a simple SQL Query:

Explode the $myFrieds and $users_friends arrays, then use the [array_intersect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) function to find the common entries, and [count()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) those

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**array_intersect**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php):

```
$common_friends = array_intersect($my_friends, $users_friends);
```