# Finding common elements in multiple arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have four arrays and I want to get the common elements of each array. Is there a function that will allow me to compare multiple arrays and get their common element?

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 121186
        [1] => MPE129
        [2] => MHB1
        [3] => 60000
        [4] => 2014-2015
        [5] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 102147
        [1] => MPE129
        [2] => MHB1
        [3] => 60000
        [4] => 2014-2015
        [5] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 130879
        [1] => MPE129
        [2] => MHB1
        [3] => 60000
        [4] => 2014-2015
        [5] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 101768
        [1] => MPE129
        [2] => MHB1
        [3] => 60000
        [4] => 2014-2015
        [5] => 1
    )
```

Comment: Use `foreach(){foreach(){}}` to compare

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array_intersect()

$intersect = array_intersect($array1,$array2,$array3);
```

If you don't know how many arrays you have, then build up an array of arrays and user `call_user_func_array()`

```
 $list = array();
 $list[] = $array1;
 $list[] = $array2;
 $list[] = $array3;
 $intersect = call_user_func_array('array_intersect',$list);
```

Reference [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5299634/1687983)

Answer (score 2):

Try array_intersect to find the common element of any array.

```
$result = array_intersect($array[0],$array[1],$array[2])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using PHP's own function [array_instersect()](http://php.net/array_intersect)

Comment: Rushing an answer that merely points to the manual is not as helpful as actually demonstrating the technique (which other answers have done).  When you just want to drop a link to the manual, post a comment under the question instead of posting an answer.