# PHP Count Similiar Values in multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have values in database like these :

```
Row 1 : ["2","3"]
Row 2 : ["1","3"]
Row 3 : ["2","3","4"]
```

In frontend i selected all rows, now i want to show count of similar values.
For eg : Desired o/p from above code : Count for 1 = 1 , 2 = 2 , 3 = 3 , 4 = 1

When i json_decode above values and using print_r i got like these :

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 ) 
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 )
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 )
```

**Note** : List of rows can be increased, how can i find similar values.

I tried array_intersect as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299608/find-common-values-in-multiple-arrays-with-php) , but didn't work.

Eg: image here
[Please Note Data in image, is different from above data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73Z0D.png)

Code to get above data :

```
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "ams");
    $query="SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE subject = '$subj'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);


<table class="table table-responsive">
            <tr>
                <th>Sr. No</th>
                <th>Col 1 </th>
                <th>Col 2</th>
            </tr>
            <form method="post">
                <?php
                $i=1;
                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                            $data = $row['att'];
                            $data = json_decode($data);

                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>" . $i . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['date1'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . print_r($data) . "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                            $i++;
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </form>
            </table>
```

Comment: I'm confused. What database are you using?

Comment: I am using MYSQL Database

Comment: You shouldn't be getting that as a response. What driver are you using to connect to Mysql? Can you please show some code in this question. It is very vague.

Comment: Can I give you an answer in PDO? I am not exactly sure how to leverage `mysqli_`?

Comment: @McStuffins : Yes no problem

Comment: Do you mind providing me the column name in SQL that you are attempting to get?

Comment: @McStuffins Column Name : att

Answer (score 0):

So, I made this class for you. It will create the connection when you initalize it.

```
class RowData {

    private $connection;
    private $returnContent = array();
    private $stmt = null;

    function __construct() {
        $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=" . MYSQL_HOST . ";dbname=" . MYSQL_DB, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD);
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    public function get($subj) {
        $this->getContentFromDB($subj);
        $this->parseContent();
        return $this->returnContent;
    }

    private function getContentFromDB($subj) {
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE subject = '{$subj}'");
        $stmt->execute();
        $this->stmt = $stmt;
    }

    private function parseContent() {
        $content = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        if(count($content) < 1) {
            throw new Exception('Unable to find any attendies');
        }
        foreach($content as $values) {
            $row = $this->getJsonArray($values->att);
            $this->findValues($row);
        }
    }

    private function getJsonArray($content) {
        return json_decode($content);
    }

    private function findValues(array $row) {
        foreach($row as $key => $value) {
            if(isset($this->returnContent[$value])) {
                $this->returnContent[$value] = $this->returnContent[$value] + 1;
            } else {
                $this->returnContent[$value] = 1;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

So, let me explain it. The constructor will be the function that is initialized when you write `$x = new RowData();`. It creates the connection the the MySQL database. All you have to do is change the MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_DB, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD values to the appropriate ones. The only function that is available for you to use publicly would be the `get()` function. The `get()` function calls 2 separate functions and accepts one value as a parameter. The one value is what you called `$subj`. One of the functions in the `get()` function just gets the content from the MySql Table using the query you provided. The second function `parseContent()` gets an obj from PDO and loops through it. lastly, there is the `findValues()` function that accepts `$row` as a parameter. This function will see if the number is already in the data set. If it is, then it is basically a counter. Otherwise, it makes a new key and sets the value to 1.

The values returned from the `get()` function would be something like this:

```
array(2=>2, 1=>1, 3=>3, 4=>1)
```

To use this class, you would write something like this:

```
$rowData = new RowData();
try {
    $content = $rowData->get();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // No results were found
}
```

Hope this helps! If you need help implementing this, let me know and i'll be more than happy to help you out!