# Finding same values on multiple array data PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I got this case. I want to return same value that contain from all array data.

```
$arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,9,14];
$arr2 = [1,2,10];
$arr3 = [1,2,5];
$arr4 = [1,2,3,5];
```

The return array value after filtering should :

```
$finalArr = [1, 2];
```

Why 1, 2? Because it's contain in all array data. Then how to filter between array data and to finding final array in PHP? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with asking for a bit of help with your homework. Beginners are welcome, but we expect a good faith attempt at an answer from you first. 
___SO is not a free coding service___ although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.
[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Check https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: I think like this `print_r(array_intersect($arr1, $arr2, $arr3, $arr4));`

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's not a homework. A website project. 1, 2 is a data_id.

Comment: Thanks @executable and The fourth bird it's work!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find common values in multiple arrays with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299608/find-common-values-in-multiple-arrays-with-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works!

```
$arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,9,14];
$arr2 = [1,2,10];
$arr3 = [1,2,5];
$arr4 = [1,2,3,5];


$duplicates = checkduplicate($arr1, $arr2, $arr3, $arr4);

print_r($duplicates);

function checkduplicate($arr1, $arr2, $arr3, $arr4)
{
    $keys = [];
    foreach($arr1 as $key)
    {
        if(in_array($key, $arr2) && in_array($key, $arr3) && in_array($key, $arr4))
        {
            $keys[] = $key;
        }
    }

    return $keys;
}
```

This iterates over all the items in the first array, and check if they also contain in the others

You can also use array intersect, which takes multiple arrays

```
$duplicates = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2, $arr3, $arr4);
```

Comment: Why don't use the php function `array_intersect` ?

Comment: Check my second option :)

Comment: I use the second option :) thanks! @Timberman

Comment: @behzadmsalehi why wouldnt it work then? Then you will still get the response you want?

Comment: @Timberman yes you are right, I make a mistake, sorry.